# Mysql data recovery

Tags: mysql, disaster-recovery, database-restore

The linux machine on which we have the mysql has crashed due to a power failure. This probably caused the mysql server to crash too and we are not now able to restore/backup/export the database from it using the standard command line commands. Are there any mysql tools which help in recovering this data ?

Answer (score 2):

Chances are good that you have got your tables and/or indexes damaged. Depending on what errors you get, you should use the [CHECK TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/check-table.html) and [REPAIR TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/repair-table.html) statements. There is some more information on possible advanced recovery procedures in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-repair.html).

A backup is always good to have before doing stunts with important data - so don't forget to stop the mysql daemon and copy the entire /var/lib/mysql directory somewhere else before running ***any*** recovery commands.

Comment: +1 especially for the tip about making a backup first

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should check the filesystem (fsck.ext3).

Which are the mysql errors?

Answer (score 0):

After surfing the information on web about such tool, I found some good utility like Stellar Phoenix MySQL database recovery software. Although paid but claim to recover the database in every corruption scenario. The tool also repairs damaged MySQL tables created in Linux operating systems. Evaluate the software yourself by trying its demo version and check whether it worth the data need to recovered or not